# Why is vim leaving temporary file versions all over the place?

Tags: vim

First of all I assume those files ending with "~" which are created by vim when editing a file are indeed serving the purpose of temporary backups while editing.

But every time I open a file with vim and close it (:wq) I afterwards find such a file~. Why is vim not cleaning up? I assume there is something not correctly configured.

Comment: They are not temporary backup files; they are the previous versions of the files.  In a directory under version control they tend to become a nuisance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can disable backup files putting this line in your vimrc file:

> set nobackup

But if you still want to backup your files, centralize it to a directory with:

> set backupdir=~/tmp

for example.

Comment: thanks - but is this really the intended behaviour? I mean even when I do not change anything in the file those files are created and remain after closing vim. I assume (intuitively) that vim must be able to get rid of those files when closing!? I would not like to disable it as it might be of use when vim crashes. The backupdir-solution seems to be a good compromise though

Comment: Yes; They are backup files; the default behavior is to create those backup files.

Comment: @Яaffael, the `backup` option is off by default, you should read the doc before enabling an option.

Comment: @Яaffael The `.swp` files are used when vim crashes, not the backups

Comment: The backup files are created when you write the file. If you haven't changed anything, why did you write it? If you just habitually do `:w` maybe you could do `:up` instead which will only save if there are changes.

Answer (score 5):

> First of all I assume those files […] are indeed serving the purpose of temporary backups while editing.

No. They are *non*-temporary backups made *when saving*.

The temporary files created *while editing* are (on UNIX-alike platforms) named `.wibble.swp` (for a file named `wibble`).

```
:help backup
```

in `vim` itself explains the former, including the rules for when backup files are created and when they are not.

```
:help swap
```

gives explains the latter.

Comment: 1) what does "gen" mean? 2) what purpose do those non-temporary backups serve?

Comment: [Allgemeine Informationen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gen#English).

Comment: With that link, you force readers to look through definitions until one makes sense. Why not just _say_ it's an informal world for "information"?